# r code for inverse of Yeo Johnson Transformation?

Tags: r

I use YJ transformation for predictor variables and try to plot the model between predicted and observed values. Could you please help me to do this?
I am looking for a r code for inverse of Yeo-Johnson transformation.

Answer (score 5):

There's an answer to this in the comments for [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60202/r-code-for-yeo-johnson-transformation) over at Cross Validated. [Here's the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.0-3/topics/yeo.johnson) for VGAM::yeo.johnson (use `inverse = TRUE`).